# Destination Host Unreachable - routing?

Tags: networking

This is the routing table on machine with ip 188.165.246.xxx.
The problem is local network coming in via 10.10.10.0 fails to be forwarded to internet.

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         188.165.246.xxx 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
0.0.0.0         188.165.246.xxx 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr1
188.165.246.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
188.165.246.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
```

This is a ping from 10.10.10.10

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Is it a case of another route needs to be added if so what?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't route from source `10.0.0.0/8` (which includes source 10.10.10.1) to destination in the public internet (which includes destination 8.8.8.8). [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) specifies that the answer surely won't reach you.

The enclosure that doesn't send/receive packets outside of it is collectively made of three ranges:

```
10.0.0.0/8
172.16.0.0/12
192.168.0.0/16
```

Another separate enclosure:

```
127.0.0.0/8
```

Public routers obey these rules, so even if you override your own routers, nobody will answer you.

You need to configure **SNAT** (or a variant of SNAT called masquerade, in case you have a dynamic public IP).